# Which creatures have Negative Energy Affinity (Ex)*

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, npc

I've been looking into creating a corporeal, Good NPC with Negative Energy Affinity but I'm not mad keen on them being a Dhampir. Are there any other pre existing options or am I better off homebrewing some sort of curse or new creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Races: Damphirs

That is a racial trait exclusive to [Damphirs](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-dhampir/), and no other published playable races has it.

### Custom Races

Using the [race creation rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races/) from the [Advanced Race Guide](https://paizo.com/products/btpy8rv2), you can give a race, or a race variant, the Negative Energy Affinity racial trait for -1 RP (yep, it takes away a point):

> **Negative Energy Affinity (–1 RP)**
>
> Prerequisites: None.
>
> Weakness: A member of this race is alive, but is healed by negative energy and harmed by positive energy, as if it were an undead creature.

As you can see, this racial trait not exactly powerful, as it works as a double-edged sword, so it is perfectly fine to give it to a variant of a more common race, due to their heritage with some unknown creature that had such ability.

### Creatures: Several

The list of creatures that have [Negative Energy Affinity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Negative_Energy_Affinity_Ex) (the universal monster ability of same name) is a little larger:

> [Dreamspawn Hungry Fog](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Dreamspawn%20Hungry%20Fog), [Hungry Fog](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Hungry%20Fog), [Sceaduinar](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sceaduinar), [Taniniver](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Taniniver), [Telgrodradt](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Telgrodradt), [Tomb Giant](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Tomb%20Giant), [Trench Mist](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Trench%20Mist), [Urdefhan](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Urdefhan), [Vermlek](http://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Vermlek).

Out of those, only the *Urderfhan* are remotely humanoid, but if you consider creating a new race, or variant of an existing race, that somehow *inherits* the ability from another creature, those other creatures have some good flavor behind them.

Comment: Hardly necessary for your answer; but if they're creating things the third party [Unholy Template]( https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/unholy-creature-cr-1/) has something akin to Negative Energy affinity in **unholy body**.

Comment: You can generate links in comments using [placeholder]( url).

Comment: By the way, consider writing that as an answer instead!

Answer (score 3):

#### You can make a custom race or be an oracle.

Unfortunately, all the existing races with Negative Energy Affinity (besides the dhampir) are very powerful, very evil, and minimally humanoid in appearance. However...

If you create a custom race, Negative Energy Affinity is one of the racial traits you can select:

From the PFSRD, on [creating custom races](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races/#TOC-Weakness-Racial-Traits):

> **Negative Energy Affinity (–1 RP)**
> Prerequisites: None.
> Weakness: A member of this race is alive, but is healed by negative energy and harmed by positive energy, as if it were an undead creature.

Alternately, your character could have 1 level in oracle with the lich curse from the Horror Realms campaign setting book.

From the PFSRD, on [oracle curses](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses/):

> **Lich (Curse of Corruption)**
> ...
> You have (unknowingly) fulfilled most (but not all) of the ritualistic components to achieve lichdom. You have yet to turn into an undead creature, but you are close. You take damage from positive energy and heal from negative energy as if you were undead.
> ...